# Java check if ArrayList<Cars> contains object

Tags: java

I've an `ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();`
And I'd like to check if object Car car exists in this carList.
What is the easiest way to check it ?

```
public boolean contain(Car car) {
   ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try searching. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Override hashcode and equals method also

Comment: depends on your `Car` implementatoin and what you think is `contain`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the java.util.ArrayList.contains(Object) method returns true if this list contains the specified element.

```
public boolean contain(Car car) {
   return carList.contains(car);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method contains(Object). Like this:

```
public boolean contain(Car car) {
   return carList.contains(car);
}
```

Use the java api to check the methods that you can use, [ArrayLists methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

All the answers above are correct, however the explanation falls short.
`List<Car>.contains(Car car)` only returns true if `car.equals(any element in the list)`. 
You can control this behavior by @Overriding equals() and hashCode() in your Car class.
The default implementation for equals() only returns true if the two objects are the same instance (i.e car1 == car2).

Answer (score 0):

There is already a method `contains` in `ArrayList` through which you can check if an object exists in an `ArrayList`. 
You can use it as follows

```
carList.contains(car));
```

It will return `true` if the object exists and `false` otherwise